# matplotlib Speeding up plotting lines in loop

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have several subplots that I've created using matplotlib. Once I plot the data, I need to go back and draw lines between data points in a for loop. My data file is large and this takes python a very long time...

Is there a way to speed this up? Here is my code:

```
def generateHistogram(x, y, ax):
    x = np.log10(x)
    xerror = []

    numData = len(x)

    plt.rcParams['lines.solid_capstyle'] = 'butt'

    for dataIndex in range(0, numData-1):
        xerror.append(np.divide(np.subtract(x[dataIndex+1], x[dataIndex]), 2.0))

    for errorIndex in range(0, len(x)):
        if (errorIndex == 0):
            ax.semilogx((np.power(10, (x[errorIndex]-xerror[errorIndex])), np.power(10, x[errorIndex])),
                        (y[errorIndex], y[errorIndex]), linewidth=2, color='k')

        if (errorIndex == len(xerror)):
            ax.semilogx((np.power(10, x[errorIndex]), np.power(10, (x[errorIndex]+xerror[errorIndex-1]))),
                        (y[errorIndex], y[errorIndex]), linewidth=2, color='k')

        if (errorIndex < len(xerror)):
            ax.semilogx((np.power(10, x[errorIndex]), np.power(10, (x[errorIndex]+xerror[errorIndex]))),
                         (y[errorIndex], y[errorIndex]), linewidth=2, color='k')
            ax.semilogx((np.power(10, (x[errorIndex+1]-xerror[errorIndex])), np.power(10, x[errorIndex+1])),
                        (y[errorIndex+1], y[errorIndex+1]), linewidth=2, color='k')

            verticleLineXPos = np.power(10, (x[errorIndex]+xerror[errorIndex]))
            ax.semilogx((verticleLineXPos, verticleLineXPos), (y[errorIndex], y[errorIndex+1]),
                        linewidth=2, color='k')


    return xerror;
```

This basically draws line on each of the subplots (where the x-axis is in a semilogx scale) at the positions I need. Do you have any suggestions for improving the performance?

Comment: Can you provide a _minimal_ example of what sort of data structure x and y are in this case?  If  these are 1D arrays, your first loop is `xerror = np.diff (x)  / 2`.  Can you post a picture of what you are trying to do?  You might also want to look into a `LineCollection` artist.

Comment: The x, y, and xerror data structures are each just a list of floats. The loops are used to calculate the length and position of the lines I need to draw. The details of this are not important to the question.

I am asking about how to efficiently plot multiple lines on a plot using matplotlib. Does LineCollection actually give an increase in performance over plotting each one? Is there a way to get better speed ups?

Comment: this might be better placed over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Right, but I suspect much of the problem is that you have a loop _at all_.  I think what you need here is `ax.vlines` http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this reference here, which provides a clever way to optimize this: http://exnumerus.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-quickly-plot-multiple-line.html

It provides a 99% speed-up in performance. It worked nicely for me.

Comment: Seperating line segments by None works greate. This tip should be written in the document of matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

**When you need to pass in different kwargs to different lines**

[grover's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982456/537098)  is ideal for when you don't need to pass any additional `kwargs` to individual lines.

However, if you do (as I did) then you can't use the one-call approach outlined in his link.

After examining where `plot` takes it's time, particularly when plotting many lines on the same axis using a loop, it turns out that much time is wasted on **autoscaling** the view after each internal `Line2D` object is added.

To get around this, we can just reuse the internals of the `plot` function ([see here on the github repo](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1344)), but only calling the `autoscale_view` function once, when we're done.

This provides a speed up of ~x2, which while not anywhere near 
to the speed up afforded by passing all plot arguments at once, is still useful for situations where you need pass in different `kwargs` (such as specific line colors).

Example code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nlines = 1000
Npoints = 100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xdata = (np.random.rand(Npoints) for N in range(Nlines))
ydata = (np.random.rand(Npoints) for N in range(Nlines))
colorvals = (np.random.rand() for N in range(Nlines))

for x, y, col in zip(xdata, ydata, colorvals):
    ax.add_line(
        plt.Line2D(
            x,y,
            color=plt.cm.jet(col)
        )
    )
ax.autoscale_view()
```